# Changing parent element value property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html code like this:

```
<td value='3' style='text-align: center'>
<select class='selection' onchange=''>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
</td>
```

What i want to do is change value of `select` parent - `td` to selected one on `onchange` event. How can i accomplish that?

PS as you can see that is `td` - so i have multiple rows and cannot assign `id` to td/select

Comment: please show us code of `PresaberiSve()`. As well as `td` don't have `value` attribute. Use `data-attributes`instead

Comment: `PresaberiSve()` is not affecting code anyhow. I will edit code and delete it so it doesn't confuse you

Comment: They issue is that you are trying to change the "value property" of something that doesn't have a "value property" - so what you are *actually trying to do* **in your code** will provide the answer.  You have not (yet) provided that information.  As to "how can I accomplish that" - the basic answer is: you can't - as it's not something that makes any sense. (so we need to see what you think that means, ie with your js code).

Comment: At a guess, you might want: `$(".selection").change(function() { $(this).closest("td").attr("value", $(this).val()); });`

Comment: @freedomn-m I do not understand. `td` has `value` property of `3`

Comment: not clear what what you're aiming for. Some further explanations would help.

Comment: Ah, I see, that's not "valid" html (but allowed), which is what was confusing the issue.   See my updated comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want something like this ?

```js
function PresaberiSve(obj){
  $("td").removeClass("active");
  $(obj).closest("td").addClass("active");
}
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:yellow;
  border: 10px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td value='3' style='text-align: center'>
<select class='selection' onchange='PresaberiSve(this);'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
</td>

<td value='3' style='text-align: center'>
<select class='selection' onchange='PresaberiSve(this);'>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is what i wanted but not inside that function. I will just create new one. Thank you.

Comment: yup you can modify this and create code as per your need :)

Comment: @AleksaRistic check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52113284/7616528)

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple :)

```
<td value='3' style='text-align: center'>
    <select class='selection' onchange='this.parentNode.setAttribute("value", this.value);'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

or you can use script element to do this:

```
<td value='3' style='text-align: center'>
    <select class='selection'>
        <option value='1'>1</option>
        <option value='2'>2</option>
        <option value='3'>3</option>
    </select>
</td>

<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('.selection').forEach(function(e){
        e.onchange = function(){ e.parentNode.setAttribute('value', e.value); });
    });
</script>
```